# Run methods annotated with @Category from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have a test class with multiple test methods that I would like to group by some criteria. For this purpose, using JUnit's `@Category` annotation on a method level seemed like a fine solution:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    @Category(AssignmentServiceCategory.class)
    public void testMethod1() {}

    @Test
    @Category(OtherCategory.class)
    public void testMethod2() {}
}
```

I would like to create different run configurations in IntelliJ IDEA for those separate categories so that only the test methods annotated with certain category are executed. My configuration looks like this:
[image: IntelliJ IDEA JUnit run configuration]

However, when I run this, all of the tests from the class where the method is declared are run, instead of only the ones annotated with specified category. Is my configuration incorrect, or does IDEA allow only class-level `@Category` annotations?

Versions:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (181.4203.550)
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b20 amd64
- JUnit 4.12

Comment: In that case, what is the purpose of specifying the category in the run configuration in IDEA, if I still have to create a suite?

Comment: The categories can be used as a filter for all the test cases in a class

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I'd like to do - but it seems that it IDEA doesn't work like that. In the screenshot I've provided, there is no test class specification, only the name of the category, just like when executing the tests from a category via maven. Your solution with a suite serves the same purpose, but involves creating an additional class - but if I had multiple classes with the `@Category` annotation, I wouldn't need an extra suite to execute the methods from these categories. However, it seems to me that I can't do this with method-level annotations. Is that correct?

Comment: Hmmm, addressing one thing at a time.  In your screenshot, you have two categories `SomeCategory` and `OtherCategory`, however, in the text field of the dialog, you have entered `AssignmentServiceCategory` - so it seems that something is missing.  Do you want to confirm this category is correct?

Comment: The names in the code are just dummy ones - I will edit my question so it's clear. To clarify my question - if I annotated the `TestClass` with `@Category(AssignmentServiceCategory.class)` and kept the same configuration, I wouldn't need to create a test suite and all methods from the class will be executed (as expected). However, if I keep it at method level, the behaviour is the same, which seems kinda weird to me.

Comment: and you have the necessary interfaces?

Comment: The setup is (simplified) the same as I've shown in the question, plus the category declarations (empty classes).

Comment: empty classes or interfaces?

Comment: Classes, but I have tried both classes and interfaces and neither of it makes any change.

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue and could not... let me edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

I tried to reproduce the issue and could not.

Here's my Test Class

```
package com.mytests.category;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

public class MyTest {
    @Test
    @Category(PerformanceTests.class)
    public void testMethod1() {
        System.out.println("method1");
    }

    @Test
    @Category(RegressionTests.class)
    public void testMethod2() {
        System.out.println("method2");
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the necessary interfaces.  In JUnit, you need to create marker interfaces to represent the categories:

```
package com.mytests.category;

public interface RegressionTests {}
```

and

```
package com.mytests.category;

public interface PerformanceTests {}
```

Then in IntelliJ, I ran the tests once and it creates a configuration for me automatically. Then I edit the configuration

[image: Config Screenshot]

The results were as expected: 
Only `testMethod1` was executed.

**OLDER ANSWER**

Or from IntelliJ's Doc (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html)

> **Category**  Select this option if you only want to run test classes and
>   test methods that are annotated either with the category given with
>   the `@IncludeCategory` annotation, or a subtype of this category. Fill in the following fields:
>
> **Category**  Specify the desired category. Type category name, or click
>   browseButton and select the desired category in the dialog that opens.

Or You could create a `TestSuite` and specify (in there) which categories the suite is to include.

Something like

```
package org.mytests.category;

import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(RegressionTests.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ClassA.class, ClassB.class, ClassC.class})
public class RegressionTestSuite {
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer, I really appreciate the effort you've made in order to help me. Unfortunately, my issues still persist, and I have the same setup as you do - I have also minimized the code and create new class and category interfaces, but still without any change. I now have 3 methods - two different categories and one without any, and all are executed at once.
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (181.4203.550), JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b20 amd64 and JUnit 4.12, if it might be anyhow relevant.

Comment: @OndraK. I wonder if there is anything else at play.  For example, you are using JRE (I am using JDK) - can you try pointing your JRE to the location of your JDK?

Comment: I doubt that this is the reason, I'd bet more on the versions of either idea, or junit. What versions are you using?

Comment: I got the same version of JUnit (4.12), Using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.4892.42, built on May 7, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b38 amd64

Answer (score 0):

I have (had) the same problem with Intellij 2020.1.2
There seems to be a bug related to what setting you select for `search for tests`.

If i choose `in single module` *all* the test are executed, even the ones annotated with other Categories.

If I choose any of the other options (`in whole project`, `across module dependencies`) it simply works as expected..